CatboostError for easy training without description
not so long ago I taught the model, got the results and everything approx. Now I needed to restart the project and everything stopped working for me, namely the error on catboost.
python==3.10.5
catboost==1.2.2
X = df_train.drop(columns=['type_answer'])
y = df_train['type_answer']
 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, 
    test_size=0.15, 
    stratify=y, 
    random_state=42
)
 
enc = TargetEncoder(cols=X.select_dtypes('object').columns)
X_train_encoded = enc.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
X_test_encoded = enc.transform(X_test)

models = {
    'Random Forest': RandomForestClassifier(
        class_weight='balanced', random_state=42
    ),
    'XGBoost': XGBClassifier(
        scale_pos_weight=(len(y_train) -sum(y_train)) /sum(y_train), 
        random_state=42
    ),
    'CatBoost': CatBoostClassifier(
        auto_class_weights='Balanced', 
        verbose=0, random_state=42
    ),
    'LightGBM': LGBMClassifier(
        class_weight='balanced', random_state=42, verbose=-1
    )
}
 
for model_name, model in models.items():
    model.fit(X_train_encoded, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict_proba(X_test_encoded)[:, 1]
    gini = gini_score(y_test, y_pred)
    print(f'{model_name}: Gini test = {round(100 * gini, 2)}%')

traceback
methods tried:

reinstalling catboost
delete old environment and install new
training separately for catboost via Pool

A big request to help with understanding the problems, because the project was launched many times earlier and there were no problems.
